# Only able to type one character at a time in React.Js Input when rendering from a function

Tags: reactjs

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNGKp.png)

I have to click the input after every character I type, because it loose focus. How can I do it, using the same function with name "InputArea".
Because this problem doesn't arises when I don't use the function and write the code directly inside return.

Answer (score 0):

Define the InputArea component outside the parent component pass props to it. Because in your case, when the state changes, the component is re-rendered, and hence the InputArea component is redeclared.

Check out this [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/code-review-avoid-declaring-react-component-inside-parent-component-1768a645f523) which addresses the same issue you have

```js
function InputArea (props) {
    return <input 
             type="text" 
             onChange={props.onChange} 
             value={props.value} 
    />

}

function ParentComponent = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    function onChange (e){
        setName(e.target.value)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <InputArea onChange={onChange} value={name} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

each time you call the setName function you rerender the InputArea function.
for fixing it you can wrap the function with a useCallBack hook or move the function out from the component.

```
  const InputArea = useCallback(() => {
    return (
           <Input .../>
    )
  }, []);
```